# What should i need pay attention to in mysql query, such as %?

Tags: mysql

For example, Search is a commonly used functions.

I will generate a query string like "SELECT * FROM table WHERE col LIKE '%{keyword}%'"

but the keyword's value is '%', it does not work, how to fix it.

In addition, what other characters need to be aware of?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use a backslash to escape the percent.  For example, if your keyword were `5% discount`, then you would use:

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE col LIKE '%5\% discount%'
```

The [documentation](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/string-comparison-functions.html#operator%5Flike) lists only two characters which have a special meaning in `LIKE`:

> `%` - matches any number of characters
>   `_` - matches any single character

If you want to use either of these characters literally in a `LIKE` expression, then you will need to escape them.